# explicit cast in a switch case statement

Tags: c, casting, switch-statement

I have a character pointer named label, and also an enumerator that contains an element named "label". How can I differentiate between them in a case statement?

```
switch((I_ARG_TYPES) progrm[i].arg[j].type){
case (I_ARG_TYPES) value:
    break;
case (I_ARG_TYPES) label:
    break;
default:
    break;
}
```

Global scope:

```
typedef enum I_ARG_TYPES {
    value, label
} I_ARG_TYPES;
```

In the same function as the switch:

```
char label[MAXLINELENGTH]
```

"Case label does not reduce to an int" on the case for label.

Comment: I don't support using anything besides "label" for the name of your local variable is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. (Similarly, if you do `float printf`, you can't call the `printf()` function in that scope.)

Solution: Don't give your local variables the same name as things from the global scope.

Comment: Fair enough... I'll just rename it.